# Chrome extension: managing multiple html pages in an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to have several html files in my extension so I can open each of them according to some conditions or events. Say I want a.html to be opened when the user chooses an option on the context menu.

I tried the following:

manifest.json:

```
{
"name":  "My extension",
"version": "1.1",
"background": { "page": ["background.html"] },
"incognito": "split",
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "contextMenus"],
"icons": { "16": "images/16.png" },
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    <script src='someWindow.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
var winID;
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function proccess_interested(info, tab){

    chrome.tabs.create({active: false}, function(newTab) {

    // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab into it.
    chrome.windows.create(
        {
            tabId:      newTab.id,
            type:       "popup",
            url:        chrome.extension.getURL('a.html'),
            focused: true
        },function(window){
                 winID = newWindow.id;
          });
    });
})

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(Msg, sender, sendResponse) {

if(Msg.close_comment_win){
    chrome.windows.remove(winID, function(){});
}
});
```

someWindow.js:

```
function hide_win()
{
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({close_win: close}, function(response) {});
}
```

a.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src='someWindow.js'></script>

head     //with tags, can't show it here
body
<input type='button' value=' Cancel ' onclick="hide_win()"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

The window is opened when context menu is clicked, but when hitting cancel, it's not closed. console.log says:  `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".` I guess the reason is that a.html is not part of the extension, **even though someWindow.js which triggers sendMessage is part of the extension**.

Including a.html in the extension through manifest isn't an option as no more than one background html page can be included.

Of course I get the same when putting `chrome.windows.remove(winID, function(){});` directly in `hide_win()` without using sendMessage.

Any ideas how to get this job done?

Comment: The problem is your inline `onclick`, try getting rid of that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I'll try and get back to you.

Comment: That was it! I can't thank you enough. You can put it as an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as the error says, it is against v2's [`content security policy`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution) to have any inline code in extension html pages. Simply move that handler to your `js` file and it should work fine.